# Java Generics Use Case

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to use Java Generics in this use case and need some help figuring out how to implement it after not finding any answers online. Here is my use case....

```
// Interface DevObject   
public interface DevObject  { 
    void addExtension(DevExtension extension);
}

// Interface DevExtension 
public interface DevExtension<T extends DevObject> {
    void start(T devObject); 
}
```

Then I create two classes that implement DevObject and DevExtension respectively like this ...

```
public class MyDevObject implements DevObject {
      void addExtension(DevExtension extension) {

      }
}


public class MyDevObjectExtension implements DevExtension<MyDevObject> {
     void start(MyDevObject devObject) {

     }
}
```

But what I really want to do is use generics to modify the addExtension method on DevObject so that it will only be able to add DevExtension instances that have their generic T value to be the same as the class that implements DevObject.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
public interface DevObject<T extends DevObject<T>> { 
    void addExtension(DevExtension<T> extension);
}

public interface DevExtension<T extends DevObject<T>> {
    void start(T devObject); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One other use case is having an AbstractDevObject class that implements the addExtension method, right now its signature is like this but not correct. "public abstract class AbstractDevObject implements DevObject" any ideas what the class signature should look like to make the use case work?

Comment: @DuncanKrebs please can you repost your class signature from your comment in backticks, so the `<Whatever>` shows up? (I'm assuming you have some)

Comment: I think I figured out the answer to my first comment it is "public abstract class AbstractDevObject<T extends DevObject<T>> implements DevObject<T> "

Comment: @AnyTurner For some reason I don't see a edit link next to my first comment as I do with my last comment posted, if you'd like I can delete it since I found the answer.